# "VPN is not configured" error on El Capitan

Tags: network, macos, vpn

I discovered this new annoying bug in El Capitan 10.11.2 running on a MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013.

Sometimes when I click on the VPN icon in the menu bar, I get "VPN is not configured" despite the fact that I configured three.  It is all resolved by going into System Preferences → Network, then unchecking and rechecking the "Show VPN Status in menu bar" checkbox.

Even though I can manually sort the issue each time, I would like a more robust and permanent solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not upgrading to a fully patched version of El Capitan? Seems like the easiest fix for this would be to upgrade to 10.11.6....

Comment: Todd, you are ~2 years too late in your comment.  MacOS 10.13.x solved the issue long ago.

Comment: The bug appears to be back with Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 1):

One workaround that I found useful was to use [Tunnelblick](https://www.tunnelblick.net) rather than macOS built-in VPN networking. Tunnelblick is open source and generally respected, and if you are able to install this software on your machine, it is a more robust and permanent solution than macOS' Networking prefpane.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above the issue was solved at some point by an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug on El Capitan and it is now back with Catalina. Connecting to the VPN via network preferences also repopulates the list like toggling show/hide does, but there is no fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching Wifi networks, and then switching back to the one you were on. Worked for me!